# Android AsyncTask, Pass view from UI Activity

Tags: android

I have a web browser application.
A AutoCompleteTextView act as a Url textbox, and being fetch a list (Cursor Type) when application start.
Below code is work well, but i don't know it correct to use AsyncTask or not.

So, did the AutoCompleteTextView  will freeze will application launch?
And i monitor the thread via Eclipse thread monitor, the AsyncTask#1 thread keep in wait status when done.So how can i close the thread???

Code:

```
public class BrowserActivity extends StandOutWindow {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //Build the layout
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_browser, frame, true);
        AutoCompleteTextView txtUrl = (AutoCompleteTextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtUrl);

        //Run the async task
        BrowserDataTask bdTask = new BrowserDataTask();
        bdTask.execute(txtUrl);
    }

    //A method belong to BrowserActivity class and reusable.
    public Cursor getBrowserData() {
        String[] projection = new String[] { "_id", Browser.BookmarkColumns.TITLE,
                Browser.BookmarkColumns.URL };
        Cursor mCur = getContentResolver().query(android.provider.Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI,
                projection, null, null, null);      
        return mCur;
    }

    //Sub Class of BrowserActivity 
    private class BrowserDataTask extends AsyncTask<AutoCompleteTextView, Integer, Cursor>
    {
        private AutoCompleteTextView m_acText;

        @Override  
        protected Cursor doInBackground(AutoCompleteTextView...params) {  
            m_acText = params[0];
            return getBrowserData();
        }  

        @Override  
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {  
            super.onProgressUpdate(progress);  
        }  

        @Override  
        protected void onPostExecute(Cursor result) {  
            //UrlAdapter, custome Cursor Adapter from other class.
            UrlAdapter adapter = new UrlAdapter(BrowserActivity.this, result);
            m_acText.setAdapter(adapter);
        } 

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why is it waiting?

`AyncTask` uses `ThreadPoolExecutor` and hence you they might not get destroyed but rather kept, because destroying and reinitializing them would be a definite waste. In case you really want to close it, call `cancel()` on it, that might help.

Will it freeze the app?

No, it won't.

Also, you are never setting your progress!